# Filter report by date to show users registered this week through email in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with startDate and StopDate as parameters. I also configured smtp settings etc to send a report through email on specified time which is working fine. I am getting the stopDate from today() function but I dont know how to keep the startDate to Monday of the week. I need to automatically send report through email containing the number of users registered in this week i.e. from Monday to Monday on Monday, from monday to tuesday on Tuesday and finally from Monday to Friday on Friday. Same patterns in next week. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the expression below:

=IIF(Weekday(today())=1,DateAdd("d",-6,today()),DateAdd("d",2-Weekday(today()),today()))